# MySql text rows to columns (transpose)

Tags: mysql, transpose

There are plenty of examples here to accomplish the contrary - columns to rows. But not this.

The rows have URLs like this:

color:black    http://www.example.com/1/http://www.example.com/2/http://www.example.com/3/http://www.example.com/4/

I need to get them into individual rows for each url like this:

```
color           URL
color: black    http://www.example.com/1/ 
color: black    http://www.example.com/2/ 
color: black    http://www.example.com/3/
color: black    http://www.example.com/4/
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in MySql?

Comment: Your data is not clear.  Is that one messed up string with no delimiters?  Is it multiple columns?

Answer (score 0):

If these are in different columns, you can do:

```
select color, url1 as url from t
union all
select color, url2 from t
union all
select color, url3 from t
union all
select color, url4 from t;
```

The following might work:

If they are in one messed up column (as suggested by the example), then something like:

```
select color,
       concat('http:', substring_index(substring_index(concat(url, 'http:'), 'http:', 2), 'http:', -1)) as url
from t
union all
select color,
       concat('http:', substring_index(substring_index(concat(url, 'http:'), 'http:', 3), 'http:', -1)) as url
from t
where url like 'http:%http:%'
union all
select color,
       concat('http:', substring_index(substring_index(concat(url, 'http:'), 'http:', 4), 'http:', -1)) as url
from t
where url like 'http:%http:%http:%';
```

You would keep adding a subquery for each url that you have.

Comment: The urls are all in one row in a field, could be an unlimited number. First i need to get every single url out of this field and then get them one url per row.